# Not possible to get email id from instagram login

Tags: instagram

I am using instagram login in my website. I get the username only from instagram. I can't get the email id to check with the already existing one in my database. Is there any way to get the email id?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The bottom of this page: 
https://instagram.com/developer/authentication/ mentions the scopes that are supported and email is not one of them, so you will not get email.